# Getting an error converting data type nvarchar to float in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 queries I am trying to run in SQL Server and I keep getting the same error for both, not sure how to fix it:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float

For both queries, the error refers to the first line of the query. I included a photo of the database model I transferred over to SQL Server so there is context on the tables. If there is an easier way such as a join statement please let me know.

[Screenshot of the database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UCgT.png))

In case viewing the data pool is necessary, here is the google sheet with the data that was imported into the server [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NuRlhEBsZIyaUtyHZZXizKy0zk8JLBr5xWvsjWkHzWY/edit?usp=sharing)

For dataypes, here is the ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE [COURSE_T]
( 
    [CourseDescription]  varchar(300) NULL,
    [CourseID]           integer NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [CUSTOMER_T]
( 
    [CustomerName]       varchar(100) NULL,
    [CustomerStreet]     varchar(59) NULL,
    [CustomerCity]       varchar(50) NULL,
    [CustomerState]      varchar(50) NULL,
    [CustomerZip]        varchar(5) NULL,
    [CreditLimit]        money NULL,
    [CustomerID]         integer NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID]         integer NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [EMPLOYEE_COURSE_T]
( 
    [CompletionDate]     date NULL,
    [EmployeeID]         integer NOT NULL,
    [CourseID]           integer NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [EMPLOYEE_T]
( 
    [EmployeeFirstName]  varchar(100) NULL,
    [EmployeeLastName]   varchar(100) NULL,
    [EmployeeJobTitle]   varchar(50) NULL,
    [EmployeeStreet]     varchar(50) NULL,
    [EmployeeCity]       varchar(50) NULL,
    [EmployeeState]      varchar(50) NULL,
    [EmployeeZip]        varchar(5) NULL,
    [EmployeeHireDate]   date NULL,
    [EmployeeID]         integer NOT NULL,
    [ManagerID]          integer NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [FABRICATED_T]
( 
    [PartQuantity]       integer NULL,
    [ProductID]          integer NOT NULL,
    [PartID]             integer NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [ORDER_LINE_T]
( 
    [OrderQuantity]      integer NULL,
    [ProductID]          integer NOT NULL,
    [OrderID]            integer NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [ORDER_T]
( 
    [CustomerPONumber]   varchar(50) NULL,
    [OrderDate]          date NULL,
    [DueDate]            date NULL,
    [ShipDate]           date NULL,
    [OrderID]            integer NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID]         integer NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [PRODUCT_SUPPLIER_T]
( 
    [ProductCost]        money NULL,
    [PurchasedQuantity]  integer NULL,
    [VendorPartID]       varchar(50) NULL,
    [SupplierID]         integer NOT NULL,
    [ProductID]          integer NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [PRODUCT_T]
( 
    [ProductDescrption]  varchar(300) NULL,
    [ProductID]          integer NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice]          money NULL,
    [StockQuantity]      integer NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [SALES_REP_T]
( 
    [CommisionRate]      decimal(5,2) NULL,
    [EmployeeID]         integer NOT NULL 
)

CREATE TABLE [SUPPLIER_T]
( 
    [SupplierName]       varchar(100) NULL,
    [SupplierStreet]     varchar(50) NULL,
    [SupplierCity]       varchar(50) NULL,
    [SupplierState]      varchar(50) NULL,
    [SupplierZip]        varchar(5) NULL,
    [SupplierID]         integer NOT NULL 
)
```

**Question I**: who is the manager of the manager of the sales reps?

Hint: Show the name of the sales rep's manager's manager only, and your single SQL statement will need to determine the sales rep’s manager before it can determine the manager of the sales rep’s manager

```
SELECT 
    M.EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + M.EmployeeLastName AS ManagerOfManager
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE_T$ AS E, EMPLOYEE_T$ AS M
WHERE 
    E.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID
    AND E.EmployeeID IN (SELECT DISTINCT E.ManagerID
                         FROM EMPLOYEE_T$ AS E, SALES_REP_T$ AS SR
                         WHERE E.EmployeeID = SR.EmployeeID)
```

**Question J**: list the employee names of those that report directly to the manager of the sales manager(s).
Hint: your SQL statement must determine the sales manager before it can determine manager of the sales rep's manager, and then it must determine the names of those that report to the manager of the sales
rep's manager

```
SELECT EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + EmployeeLastName AS EmployeeName
FROM EMPLOYEE_T$
WHERE ManagerID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ManagerID
                    FROM EMPLOYEE_T$
                    WHERE EmployeeID IN (SELECT DISTINCT E.ManagerID
                                         FROM EMPLOYEE_T$ AS E,
                                              SALES_REP_T$ AS SR 
                                         WHERE E.EmployeeID = SR.EmployeeID))
```

Comment: Nowhere in the create tables script is Nvarchar mentioned and the only numeric types are money or integer. So where have you introduced nvarchar or real data types?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell I agree. Thats what I am not understanding, where is nvarchar and float even coming from if I don't even have those data types in the table. And why am I getting this issue?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Where are the table definitions for the tables _actually_ mentioned in your queries, `EMPLOYEE_T$` and `SALES_REP_T$`?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: Also, where are these queries being run?  Within SQL Server Management Studio, or through a different client front-end?

Comment: Don't delete and repost a question, it's not appreciated by the community. Edit [your original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76196594/keep-getting-error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-float-sql) instead.

Comment: Works here https://dbfiddle.uk/pJQCg6YG please show a [mcve] containing the issue. Having said that, there are side issues with your code: old-style joins, use of `DISTINCT` unnecessarily in subqueries.